# How can we add a icon in title bar using python-flask?

Tags: python, html, flask

I am trying to add an image in a title bar and after searching online I didn't got any answer that can satisfy the problem

```
 <link rel="icon" type="img/png" href="~random image link~" >
```

Comment: sorry, I had put a Base64(I don't know) link but when I used a CDN(I don't know it too) link it works. can anyone tell me what is this Base64 and CDN links?

Answer (score 1):

Put the icon in your static directory as `favicon.ico` good size for it is `16 x 16`, and now simple use `url_for` function to get that icon, from [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/favicon/#adding-a-favicon)

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}">
```

Comment: sorry, I had put a Base64(I don't know) link but when I used a CDN(I don't know it too) link it works. can anyone tell me what is this Base64 and CDN links?

Comment: what is the name of your `image`?

Comment: https://icons8.com/icon/set/profile/all - from here I thought to import the image and after generating html link for an image there was 2 options "PNG Base64" and "PNG CDN" the base 64 wasn't working but the CDN one worked fine.